# Not able change color of back button in iOS 16

Tags: ios, swiftui

[simulator output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OIPl.png)

I am not able to change default accent color of back button in NavigationStack(iOS 16)

Solutions that I've tried -

1. Adding tint color `NavigationStack`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ReceiveMoneyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("ReceiveMoneyView")
        }
        .accentColor(Color.theme.accent)
    }
}

struct ReceiveMoneyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ReceiveMoneyView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

2. using tint instead accentColor (deprecated)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ReceiveMoneyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("ReceiveMoneyView")
        }
        .tint(Color.theme.accent)
    }
}

struct ReceiveMoneyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ReceiveMoneyView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

3. Setting tint color of All navbar (this used to work in prev ios versions)

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FrontendApp: App {
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(Color.theme.accent)
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

Comment: From looking at you simulator output. Your ReceiveMoneyView is already inside NavigationStack{} and you are setting accentColor to currentView i.e ReceiveMoneyView, So try to set accentColor on the Parent NStack{}

Comment: .accentColor(.white) is working in iOS 16

Answer (score 1):

I believe using `.tint` is the way to go for this. [Fixed bug report from Marco Arment](https://gist.github.com/marcoarment/b980ff60cc45623aeb06a4121e13f354) includes the relevant code.

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension UIColor: Identifiable {
    public var id: String {
        get { self.accessibilityName }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let defaultColor = UIColor.systemBlue
    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemRed,
        .systemGreen,
        .systemYellow,
        .systemBlue,
    ]
    
    @State var navigationValue: String?
    @State var selectedColor: UIColor?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $navigationValue) {
                NavigationLink("Tint Color", value: "test")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
        } detail: {
            Text("⬆️ Back button and/or display-mode button above should change color after choosing a new color:")
            List(selection: $selectedColor) {
                ForEach(colors) { color in
                    Button {
                        selectedColor = color
                        navigationValue = nil
                    } label: {
                        Text(color.accessibilityName)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .tint(Color(uiColor: selectedColor ?? defaultColor))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I have tried .tint() as well. It didn't work